# I can't run this php script in terminal in cPanel on linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cpanel

First time I'm trying to set a cron job on my website.
Before than that, I would like to try to run it in terminal.

In my cron jobs page I've found this command to run the script:
`/usr/local/bin/php /home/functio1/public_html/path/to/cron/script`

I've created a php file and I've changed the command above to point to the right directory.
The command apparently works as I don't get any error, neither I don't get any error file in the folder where the php file is located, but nothing happens.

This is the content of the php file:

```
<?php

include "../../../db/config.php";
include "../../../telegram/functions.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_FORMAT(user_birth_date,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
    $dateOfBirth = $row["user_birth_date"];
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $diff = date_diff(date_create($dateOfBirth), date_create($today));
    $age = $diff->format('%y');
    $birthdays = "Oggi è il compleanno di: " . $row["user_name"] . " " . $row["user_surname"] . " (" . $age . " anni)";
    sendMessage("max", $birthdays);
}

?>
```

I can say the code above works.
I'm using it at the moment by pressing a button on the website.
Basically it sends me messages on telegram for each user to help me to remember their birthdays.

I would like to be executed automatically once a day, but when I try to run the file using the command above nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help,

Max

Comment: can you add an error log file for the cron and check if there are any errors? It's a good practice when working with cron jobs to redirect the output and error to a log file

Comment: Maybe add some logging to the script to see which bits are or aren't being executed. Make sure error logging in php settings is fully enabled too. And I'm not familiar with cron very well but I'm sure it will have a log file too where you can check what it's been up to

Comment: Ok there was an error on the path of both included files. Fixed, but now I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()`, looks like mysql is not installed or not available on terminal, how comes?

Comment: command-line PHP and web-based PHP are governed by different settings files, and can even be different PHP versions potentially. So based on that error I would check the php.ini for the command-line setup and check whether the mysqli extension is enabled

Comment: Thanks @ADyson that's correct. I've resolved calling the script using wget, bypassing the settings differences of the command line

Comment: Ok. Any reason you didn't just fix the command-line version of PHP in the environment?

Comment: Because I have no idea how to do it, but that’s the next step and it will take another research. Any suggestions on how to proceed? In my cPanel I can just find where to select the php version, but nothing about editing the php.ini, specially nothing mentioning the differences between command line and web based

Comment: If you're on a hosted server you should maybe ask the hosting company for support - explain the error you've got and ask them to enable mysqli on command-line php. In such an environment you may not have access to the configuration files yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks I’ll do it, because I really don’t see any other option. I’ll let you know